# Singular locus of the punctual Hilbert scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would be very grateful for any comment or a reference
on the following question.

Let $Hilb_0^n({\mathbb C}^2)$ be the Hilbert scheme
of n points in ${\mathbb C}^2$ concentrated, set theoretically,
at the origin. 
Let $X$ be the locus of $Hilb_0^n({\mathbb C}^2)$
formed by curvilinear ideals.

Is the complement of $X$ in $Hilb_0^n({\mathbb C}^2)$
a divisor or it has codimension > 1 ?

Comment: Taking n=3 shows that it is at least possible that the locus you describe has codimension >1.  Of course, it is also empty if we take n=2.  I don't know the answer off hand for all n.

Comment: What are curvilinear ideals?

Comment: Geometrically, a curvilinear ideal is an ideal corresponding to a scheme that is locally contained in a smooth curve.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from [Briançon](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/gcs-wrapper/?gcsurl=http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8086%252Fgcs%252Fgcs%253Faction%253Dpdf%2526metsFile%253DPPN356556735_0041%2526divID%253Dlog10%2526pdftitlepage%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.digizeitschriften.de%25252Fdms%25252Fpdf-titlepage%25252F%25253FmetsFile%25253DPPN356556735_0041%252526divID%25253Dlog10%2526targetFileName%253DPPN356556735_0041_log10.pdf) (Inventiones Math 41 (1977), no. 1, 45–89) Theorem III.3.1 that the codimension is 2 for n=3, and 1 for n>3.

Comment: He computes the dimension of the strata corresponding to different Hilbert functions in terms of "staircases" of initial ideals. For n>3 there is always the staircase corresponding to $(y^2,xy,y^{n-1}$ giving dimension $n-2$. The deformation is similar to that given by Martin, but I don't recall the details (and as Jack pointed out, Martin's has some problem).

Comment: Indeed I have.. I deleted the answer referred to.